# Problem in writing grade after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I built a questionnaire with four questions. I wrote the grade calculation code but as I try to insert the grade to a "p" tag after the submit button of the form was clicked, the page, as it should, refreshes itself, sends the form to the server and the grade that was calculated and printed doesn't exist and isn't showed in the page. (The submit button's type needs to stay as "submit" and not to be changed to "button"). Can you help me?
Just to try clarify my question, that's an example for what could be written in the "checkForm" function:

```js
function checkForm() {
    var gradeplace = document.getElementById("actualGrade");
    var checkvalidation = checkValidation();
    if (checkvalidation) {
        gradeplace.innerHTML = "50";
    }
}
```

The checkValidation function checks if the input fields were filled correctly and if they are ready to be sent to the server. Then I check if the function returned true and if so, inside the "p" tag that holds the id "actualGrade" there will be written "50". (I removed the grade calculation function). The submit button automatically refreshes the page so the grade is erased and is not showed.

Comment: So on submit, do you want the page to refresh? If yes, you can store grade on `sessionStorage` and access on next page load.

Comment: Can you post some code, and explain your desired outcome?

Comment: @neophytte I added a code to try and clarify what I wanted to do, if it helped you.

Comment: you might be better to calculate the grade on the server-side based on the information submitted in the form. That way malicious users can't give themselves or others an incorrect grade by manipulating the HTML or JavaScript (or by just directly submitting data to the server via a different HTTP client). The server needs to validate the information it's being given, and/or calculate the important numbers itself, without the potential for interference from the browser/client-side.

Comment: @ADyson I understood the advice you gave me, but that's actually a school homework so It doesn't really matter to me if the grade is changed by the user, since it's just my teacher :) but I'd definitely consider it. Thank you

Comment: @Yuval I see your point. But equally, getting into good habits now and understanding the way that web applications can be tampered with will serve you well in future if you decide to do any more programming (either professionally for or for a hobby). That's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I tried @Rajesh 's answer (to use the `sessionStorage` ) and it actually worked! I used it as a counter to see whenever to calculate the grade and I used it to check whenever to write it in the "actualGrade" and whenever to keep this place empty with no grade in it. Thank you all for answering though! Appreciate you very much